# Forge does not work on company server

Tags: autodesk-forge

We have an app, that works without problems on dev machine and deployed in cloud, but we are having problems setting it up on server in corporate network, where everything (e.g. views with information from database) except Forge Viewer and Forge API (e.g. upload) works.

It fails with a message "Underlying connection closed" when we are trying to get Autodesk Forge 2 legged token. We are using Autodesk Forge .Net SDK v 1.0.2.

We did additional tests and seems like all outbound API calls on the server are failing. I know there is not enough information to actually solve the problem, but I would appreciate ideas where to look for the solution.

Comment: Did your IT department block certain port(s) on the server? Did your IT department block DNS resolution? Have you tried using curl command (or postman) on the server to verify that the HTTP call can make it? Which type of server is it, and you you being a firewall and proxy? Without knowing all this, it is hard to tell what could be wrong.